# How to grant for microsoft graph application permissions using admin consent v2 end point?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-addins

I am working in Azure Application registration process to grant application permissions using V2 end point.

1. I have added "Mail.Read" as an application permission to the azure app
2. I have used following URL to give admin consent with specified scope as "Mail.Read".

   https://login.microsoftonline.com/ff63ebda-8bfe-4e14-aba1-504db5c53970/v2.0/adminconsent
   ?client_id=34dbd899-c9fa-415f-8646-28c644baf3ec
   &scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Read
   &redirect_uri=https://google.com
   &state=12345
3. I accept the requested permission without an issue.
4. I checked the given permission after accepting and Mail.Read permission is added as "Delegated Permission" which is not the expected behavior.
5. Then I tried to give consent using default scope(https://graph.microsoft.com/.default).

   https://login.microsoftonline.com/ff63ebda-8bfe-4e14-aba1-504db5c53970/v2.0/adminconsent
   ?client_id=34dbd899-c9fa-415f-8646-28c644baf3ec
   &scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
   &redirect_uri=https://google.com
   &state=12345
6. I accept the permissions successfully.
7. Then permission is added as application permission which is the expected behavior.

My requirement is to use admin consent v2 end point with **specified scopes** to grant application permissions.
I need to know what is the possible way of doing that using admin consent v2 end point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today (June 2021) it is not possible to dynamically request admin consent for an application permission (app role).

The only option today is to use `scope=.default`, which will load the APIs and permissions from the app's configured API permissions.